# Factory Service unable to load json file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a `JSON` file, `data.json`, in the same folder as the file below. When I run this however it's returning *not found*.

I have also tried putting the `$http.get` request in a factory, but same result - *not found*. I also tried changing the `.json` extension to `.txt` as was suggested elsewhere, but this also didn't work.

The rest of the code came with the angular seeds project.

Is there something i'm missing in the other files or some other trick to the get request?

```
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  });
}]);

myApp.controller('View1Ctrl', [

  '$scope',
  '$http',

  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data.json')
    .then(function(res){
      $scope.quiz = res.data
    });
}]);
```

Comment: what is an error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.json` file must not be in the same folder as the `js` file. Relative paths are resolved relative to the including `index.html` file. If you have this structure:

```
+-index.html
|-folder
| \-data.json
\-js
  \-app.js
```

You have to `$http.get("folder/data.json")` in app.js to make it work.

Comment: oh my god, i am so embarrassed. have been racking my brains over this for hours thinking i had invented a new kind of error. i didn't realise the path was relative to the index.html file rather than the js file. thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/Lf6QcyKSn4DsQrgJhUq6?p=preview

```
'use strict';

var app=angular.module('myApp.view1', [])


app.factory('mainInfo', 
  function($http) {
  var obj={};
    obj.method =function(){
       return $http.get('tag.json')

}
    return obj;
  })
app.controller('View1Ctrl', [

  '$scope',
  '$http',
  'mainInfo',

  function($scope, $http, mainInfo) {
    mainInfo.method().success(function(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response;
        debugger
    });
}]);
```

Try placing the .json file in the same folder where the js is present.